# What does logger -f filename do?

Tags: linux, logging

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) is ambiguously worded:

```
-f file    Log the specified file.
```

There's one example in the man page with no further explanation:

```
logger -p local0.notice -t HOSTIDM -f /dev/idmc
```

[POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html) is no help:

> The logger utility saves a message, in an unspecified manner and format, containing the string operands provided by the user. The messages are expected to be evaluated later by personnel performing system administration tasks.

I would expect it to log:

- ***to*** the file
- something ***about*** the file
- or something ***from*** the file

However, if I do the following:

```
$ echo "contents" > testfile
$ logger -f ./testfile "test message"
$ cat testfile
contents
$ tail /var/log/messages
Aug  4 10:00:00 hostname logger: test message
```

I get nothing having to do with "testfile" or its contents nor are its contents changed. If `testfile` doesn't exist before I issue the `logger` command I get this error message:

> logger: ./testfile: No such file or directory.

What is `logger -f` supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/logger-invocation.html) is a little clearer and provided a hint for further
testing:

> -f file
>   --file=file
>   Log the content of the specified file. If file is ‘-’ the standard input
>    is assumed.

It turns out that specifying a message overrides the specification of a file.

So this works:

```
logger -f testfile
```

and logs the contents of the file to the logfile. If the file consists of
multiple lines, each line becomes a separate entry in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Just for support to Dennis Williamson's answer

[image: simply read file and write to syslog daemon]